# Rails 4: query by id, but only include specified columns in the resulting model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

So in Rails 3.x I used to be able to say:

```
id = 123
book = Book.find(id, select: ['title', 'description'])
```

and get back a Book that had only those fields that I specified. This was really handy as it allowed me to exclude certain large columns from my queries, yet still get back working ActiveRecord entities. Especially useful in a heavily de-normalized DB situation.

Now in Rails 4 this comes with a warning:

```
[WARN] DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing options to #find is deprecated. 
Please build a scope and then call #find on it.
```

I can't quite seem to figure out the syntax for specifying column selection for a scope, so I end up with:

```
scope :my_find_by_id, -> id { where(id: id)}
```

and then calling it like:

```
Book.my_find_by_id(id).select(['title', 'description']).first
```

which seems rather verbose and silly. Is there a more idiomatic way to acomplish this in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the select method before find:

```
Book.select(:title, :description).find(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` method to get `title` and `description`:

With scope:

```
scope :my_find_by_id, ->(id) { where(id: id).first }

Book.my_find_by_id(id).select(:title, :description)
```

Comment: Hi Kien, thanks for replying, but "Book.find(id).select(:title, :description)" - that actually does not work- "private method `select' called for #<Book:0x007faf26ddf810>". And your solution using the scope, that still needs the ".first" at the end of it since it returns a relation. So it's pretty much the thing I am trying to improve upon (it does remove the need for the array and strings though, so that is helpful.) It just seems odd that Rails would remove a feature in favor of verbosity.

Comment: Hi @CaffeineComa, i checked again, pluck and select only works on array/collection proxy, sorry for bad code :)